# How to make a field which will be foreign key and primary key at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have 3 entities in my database:

- User(Id, Name, IdRole)
- Partner (Id_User, ExpiredDate)
- Department (Id_User, Prefix)

According to the `IdRole`, some records in `User` table can contain some additional data in  the `Partner` or `Department` table.

So, I want create relation `User.Id => Partner.Id_User` and `User.Id => Department.Id_User`.

`Partner.Id_User` and `Department.Id_User` must be foreign key and primary key without identity at the same time.

I've tried to do it in 2 ways:

1. Attributes

   ```
   public class Partner
   {
       [Key]
       public virtual User Id { get; set; }

       public DateTime ExpiredDate { get; set; }
   }

   public class Department
   {
       [Key]
       public virtual User Id { get; set; }

       public string Prefix { get; set; }
   }

   public class User 
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public Role IdRole { get; set; }
   }
   ```

It causes the following error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> Entity.Entity.Partner: : EntityType 'Partner' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> Entity.Entity.Department: : EntityType 'Department' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> Partner: EntityType: EntitySet 'Partner' is based on type 'Partner' that has no keys defined.
>
> Department: EntityType: EntitySet 'Department' is based on type 'Department' that has no keys defined.

1. I've tried to use fluent API

   ```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().HasOptional(f => f.Id).WithRequired(s => s.Department);
       modelBuilder.Entity<Partner>().HasOptional(f => f.Id).WithRequired(s => s.Partner);
       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
   }
   ```

The error message was thr same.

So, how can I make such tables and relations by using Code-First?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Partner
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public DateTime ExpiredDate { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public string Prefix { get; set; }
}
```